# Changes does not take effect without reboot

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I am using Pfsense :  2.2.4-RELEASE (i386)

I moved the pfsense configuration from one machine to another by full backup export-import afterwards.
And the last move was on a fresh pfsense installation, everything start working, but when I change something, it does not take effect until I reboot. It was not like that before and this is on a production network now.

I put the network back on the old machine that worked well and it end up having the same problem after a while.
I have found a post where such problem is discussed but it does not "solved from tiself" for me.

[pfense needs to be rebooted to effect a change in existing NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/506592/pfense-needs-to-be-rebooted-to-effect-a-change-in-existing-nat)

I have changed my tftp server and run the following(suggested in the post) run /etc/rc.filter_configure_sync and then I opened my system logs and found this:

```
Oct 22 13:11:42   php: rc.filter_configure_sync: Adding TFTP nat rules
Oct 22 13:11:42   php: rc.filter_configure_sync: Adding TFTP nat rules
```

If I run it again it does the same thing. But this still does not apply my last TFTP settings. 
I did factory reset on the other machine and try to do some changes, same thing. I am totally lost here and I dont know what to do anymore, I also have thread in pfsense forum from 1 month so far and keep on following it.
https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=99944.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have take a look on the services running, start to shut down services one by one.
And I find out that the problem seems to be caused by the packages : iperf and TFTP Boot
I could not stop iperf so I pretty much believe that was the faulty packages.

Confirmed : iperf made that problem for me.